# Is there any substitution for compile time hash as template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, compile-time

I am making a string class whose construction relies on its hash value:

```
template <size_t N>
static inline constexpr uint64_t hash(const char(&str)[N])
{
    //...
}

class String()
{
    // Wrong
    template <size_t N>
    String(const char(&str)[N]) { hash(str)... }

    // Right
    template <uint64_t hash, size_t N>
    String(const char(&str)[N]) { hash...}
}
```

In the wrong version, if I use "hash" as constexpr, the "str" is out of its life period. But if not, the constexpr function is meaningless. Maybe I have to treat hash value as template arguments(?)

In that case, I have to use it like:

```
    // Simple but wrong
    String str("Hello World");

    // Right but complex
    String<hash("Hello World")> str("Hello World");
    
    // The worst
    class Test
    {
    public:
        Test()
        : name("Hello World") // ???
        {}
    private:
        String name;
    }
```

Macros work, but it is also hard to use String as member variables.
Is there any better design?

Comment: Don't try to add `**` to code, it won't work.

Comment: Old question: [Compile time hash value as template arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77815045/compile-time-hash-value-as-template-arguments)

Comment: I have deleted the old question for 2 hours!

Comment: You aren't supposed to delete and repost questions verbatim. The votes and comments are feedback to improve your post. Deletion to circumvent curation is an abuse of the system.

Comment: @Slava - As fun as it is to discuss statistics that one pulls out their rear end, the truth is most questions are unvoted on despite being less than stellar. If the protectors of crap would stop fighting curators, we might actually be able to locate useful information here.

Comment: @Slava - And even *if* curators were unreasonable (which they aren't) it doesn't excuse askers ignoring feedback. If they don't edit their post when made aware of issues, those votes are **deserved**!

Comment: *"if I use 'hash' as constexpr, the 'str' is out of its life period"* -- Why is this true? The lifetime of function parameters tend to include function bodies, so what's special here? (Help other people find your question by providing a good description of the scenario.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the string literal as a template parameter once using a helper class:

```cpp
template<size_t N>
struct literal_string {
    constexpr literal_string(const char(& arr)[N]) {
        std::ranges::copy(arr, data);
    }

    constexpr operator std::string_view() const noexcept { return { data, N }; };

    char data[N];
};

template<literal_string S>
struct String {
    static constexpr uint64_t hash_value = hash(S.data);

    constexpr String() {
        // You have access to both S.data and hash_value here
    }
};

String<"Hello World"> str;
```